# Completely lost a folder converted to unkown file

Tags: windows, files, directory, chromium, bookmarks

this is blowing my mind.
I got a new fresh installed ubuntu and windows on seperated partitions.
From ubuntu, I can access windows partition so I created a folder named REPO_APP inside that contains git repository clone. I created a new bookmark linked to the folder. But after few times, I can't access it anymore because the folder was no longer a folder but a tiny file REPO_APP containing:

```
{"user_experience_metrics.stability.exited_cleanly":false,"variations_crash_streak":1}
```

I seems like related to chromium's metrics.

The folder doesn't realy matter, I can clone it again. I just want to know if there is someone else who experienced it and understand what happened.
Thanks.